# How to make dynamic Magnifying Glass effect in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, effects

I wanted to make a magnifying glass effect in one of my project.

I want this magnifying effect on full flash, i.e. even on dynamic object. So this is why i can't use large static images.

Please suggest me best way to proceed on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get very good effects through using DisplaceMap filter, look links bellow (sources included)

http://wonderfl.net/code/ce64c566e07087888ba087653bdc3a7dd81ecc83

Answer (score 0):

Here another example (but for AS2)

http://gasubasu.com/2005/10/10/defraction/